# Windows 10 Union multiple Folders to one

Tags: windows, hard-drive, links

I've got 3 Folders

- D:\Serien
- E:\
- K:\

which I would like to virtually link together to one Folder without having all of the data on one drive. (keep the data structure maybe just add a virtual drive or something?)

Do you know any way to link Folders without formating the Drives?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a folder that contains symbolic links to folders on other drives.
That's what the "mklink" command is for, and you can type "mklink /?" in a
Command Prompt window to get info on using the command.

Comment: the problem with mklink is that i cant link all 3 folders to 1 super folder :( e.g. i cant mklink /D D:\Serien E:\, because D:\Serien already exist but i want to have everything in one folder

Comment: Then no, not possible. Your options are reconfiguring partitions or RAID.